# how to compare single char in VB6?

Tags: vb6

i'm trying to do a guessing game in VB6. it involves comparing a letter that the user input. i already searched for it, unfortunately, they only have for the latest version.

can anybody help me on comparing a single char in Visual Basic6.0 . because, frankly i have no idea on it.

Comment: You haven't found any code to compare a string? Google is your friend. What have you tried so far - share your attempts in VB6

Comment: `Dim MySecretChar As String` with only 1 string in it, and the most trivial comparison can be `If Text1.Text = MySecretChar Then MsgBox("good")` but give more insight with a code snippet else we can only guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asc and Chr$ are the functions to look for.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim lSecret As Long
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim lAscChar As Long

    'Define a secret character as an ANSI code.
    lSecret = Asc("m")

    Do
        'Let the user input a single character.
        sInput = InputBox("Enter a single character. " & _
            "If more characters are entered, only the first one " & _
            "will be used. To end just click OK without entering text.")
        If Len(sInput) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        'Obtain the first character's ANSI code.
        lAscChar = Asc(sInput)

        'If the user entered the correct secret character, tell her.
        'Otherwise give a hint.
        If lSecret = lAscChar Then
            MsgBox "Great, you are a hero."
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf lSecret < lAscChar Then
            MsgBox "Nope, in the ANSI table, the correct answer is " & _
                "before this one."
        Else
            MsgBox "Nope, in the ANSI table, the correct answer is " & _
                "after this one."
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```